# Undefined reference to `libusb_handle_events_completed`

Tags: c, linux, debian, libusb

I'm trying to compile [mphidflash](https://code.google.com/p/mphidflash/) on Debian (Jessie) after re-writing the low-level USB interface to talk to libhidapi-libusb instead of libhid (which is no longer supported on Debian) but I'm getting some compiler errors that I'm not sure what do to with.

These are my includes in `usb-linux.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <usb.h>
#include <hidapi/hidapi.h>
#include "mphidflash.h"
#include <errno.h>
```

and here are the commands I've tried which error:

```
$ gcc main.o hex.o usb-linux.o -lusb -lhidapi-libusb -o mphidflash
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libhidapi-libusb.so: undefined reference to `libusb_handle_events_completed'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


$ gcc main.o hex.o usb-linux.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhidapi-libusb.a -lusb -lhidapi-libusb -o mphidflash
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhidapi-libusb.a(hid.o): undefined reference to symbol 'libusb_detach_kernel_driver'
//usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Basically, I'm getting an `undefined reference to symbol 'libusb_detach_kernel_driver'` which suggests that I'm including the libusb library incorrectly but I've no idea what else to try.

Comment: `'libusb_detach_kernel_driver'` may be this library is not present in `/usr/lib` or `/lib`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out hidapi-libusb uses libusb-1.0 and not libusb-0.1 (both of which can be installed on Debian).

I changed the includes to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
#include <hidapi/hidapi.h>
#include "mphidflash.h"
#include <errno.h>
```

And compiled with:

```
$ gcc main.o hex.o usb-linux.o -lusb-1.0 -lhidapi-libusb -o mphidflash
```

I'll be putting my changes into a git repo and I'll post the link when I'm finished.

Comment: Thank you for the hint; hope you're finished either ;-)